# write large HSSFWorkbook into OutputStream with ZipOutputStream

Tags: servlets, outputstream, zipoutputstream, hssfworkbook

Really appreciate the assistance since I am stuck here

I am Trying to download .xls file/files in zip format
Works fine when there are small amount of data like 150 records in xls file
But once the data is huge it fails to download.

it redirects to a page which looks someting like this
[image]

Here is my code

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
out = response.getOutputStream();   //response is of type HttpServletResponse , out is of type java.io.OutputStream
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(out));
for(int i=0;i < selectedObjectsToDownload.length; i++){
//fetching data from DB
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
      worksheet = workbook.createSheet("mySheet");
      workbook= getWorkbook(//data from DB);
      File fName=new File("File Path here");
      ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fName.getName());
      zos.putNextEntry(entry);
      workbook.write(zos);
}

response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + "exported filename.zip" + "\"");
zos.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.

Need to set character encoding **before opening the workbook**.

Here is the modified code

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
out = response.getOutputStream();   //response is of type HttpServletResponse , out is of type java.io.OutputStream

response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + "exported filename.zip" + "\"");
**response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");**
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(out));
for(int i=0;i < selectedObjectsToDownload.length; i++){
//fetching data from DB
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
      worksheet = workbook.createSheet("mySheet");
      workbook= getWorkbook(//data from DB);
      File fName=new File("File Path here");
      ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fName.getName());
      zos.putNextEntry(entry);
      workbook.write(zos);
}


zos.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Nope. You only needed to set headers before writing the body instead of after writing the body (simply because headers are headers not footers). You've moved the setContentType() and setHeader() to top at the same time. *That* was the solution. The setCharacterEncoding() has only effect when you use response.getWriter() instead of response.getOutputStream(). So the setCharacterEncoding() call is useless in this context.